# Touchable Highlight was not working in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm using touchable highlight onPress was not working

Here's my code

```
<View style={styles.savebtnview}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.saveButtonStyle} onPress={() => this._submitform()}>
                      <Text style = {styles.saveButtonTextStyle}>
                            SAVE
                      </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

And this my submitForm action

```
_submitform = () =>{
  Alert.alert(
    'Sample',
    'Success'
    );
}
```

Here's my CSS

```
savebtnview:{
  flexDirection: 'row',
  margin: 10
},

saveButtonStyle: {
  height: 50,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderRadius: 10,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: '#0e3a5e',
},

saveButtonTextStyle: {
fontSize: 20,
color: 'white',
alignSelf: 'center'
},
```

If I click the button the alert is not coming.  Where am doing wrong? Anyhelp could be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you import Alert? Instead of alerting, insert also console.log for debugging into your submitform function

Comment: Here's a working version of your code: https://snack.expo.io/rJbzVX-XZ

Comment: Yes I had imported Alert. console.log is not printing anything

Comment: Then your function is not being invoked. Hmm. It may be about stylings, are you sure you can click the button?

Comment: @Sivagami which error display?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/SJWQIXZmZ it still works.

Comment: show me your render hierarchy, there may be onPress conflicts.

Comment: you can write this `onPress={this._submitform.bind(this)}`

Comment: @EnieJakiro Am trying to add button on screen bottom. From the top there will be three textboxes

Comment: I cant help you further.

Comment: @NidhiPatel not working. As per my understanding onPress={this._submitform.bind(this)} and onPress={() => this._submitform()}  both are same.

Comment: did you try logging something (not in function but directly in noPress like this: onPress={() => console.log("button pressed")}. Also check if this._submitform is a function or not (I mean whether you have access to that or not)